# Javascript works in Chrome, but not in IE or Firefox

Tags: javascript, asp.net, internet-explorer, firefox, google-chrome

When one or fewer checkboxes are selected and you click the Compare tours button, a popup should appear. However, this functionality is ONLY working in Chrome. What can I do to make it work in Firefox and IE?

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder" runat="Server">
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var selectedCheckboxes = $("input:checkbox[id$=Select]");
        $("[id*=CompareTop]").click(function() {
            if (selectedCheckboxes.filter(":checked").length <= 1) {
                event.preventDefault();
                alert("Please select at least 2 tours to compare.");}
        });            
        selectedCheckboxes.change(function() {
            if (selectedCheckboxes.filter(":checked").length > 3){
                $(this).removeAttr("checked");
                alert("At most 3 tours may be compared.");  
            }
        });
    });

          </script>
<sc:Placeholder ID="phHeader" Key="ph_header" runat="server" />
```

Comment: I'd start with adding "});" at the end of the script.

Comment: It is being closed, I cut out some j/s that functions properly that follows, and the $(document).ready is closed out there - I simply forgot to include it here.

Comment: Have you tried running it with Firebug open in firefox? This will help debug the issue.

Comment: Yes - with help from a friend, we decided we may need to pass in "event" as a parameter - I will update this once I conclude if that is the solution.

Comment: Your friend is correct. As it stands now, `event.preventDefault()` is not going to work because you don't have a variable named `event` in the function (at least as far as we can see).

Comment: Right-  it still works in Chrome though - would you have any idea why it does so?

Comment: more of a work flow suggestion, but can you change it so that the "Compare Tours" is *disabled* when not enough checkboxes are checked? this eliminates a popup, which no one ever really likes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function should take an argument called "event", no?  The fact that it does not is certainly why it doesn't work in Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

You are Missing a }); at the end. you need to close the $(document).ready

Comment: sorry, I actually excluded some more j/s code that functions properly, and the $(document).ready is closed there.